# focus back to parent object failing in latest version of chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asp-classic, focus, parent-child

**background:** 
i have developed and maintain and a web based sales system using classic asp, javascript and sql server for internal use. to minimise my workload I restrict access to system so that only IE and Chrome browsers can be used.

**problem**
following latest chrome upgrade (Version 34.0.1847.116), routines that have been working perfectly are no longer working in chrome. IE is fine.

**overview**
i use parent to call child window. search for data in child, then return variables back to parent, which closes child, processes variables and updates parent form. I use this in lots of screens within the system and i find it provides a neat and intuitive UI.

However, from what I have read, Google Chrome has now restricted this functionality and there are no workarounds. It is such a useful function, I wanted to ask who uses pop up windows in this way and what solutions are there? Thanks so much in advance for your advice.

**code**

*parent: calls new child window:*

```
<a href="javascript: upload(0)" name="custPicker" id="custPicker">Add Customer</a>

function upload(){
....
newWindow2 = window.open(newWindow2Ref, "custWin", features);
}
```

*child: pop up to search and find customer and then passes back variable (custId) to opener giving field dummy1 the focus*

```
opener.document.star.dummy1[<%=passedptr%>].value = "<%=custId%>";   
opener.document.star.dummy1[<%=passedptr%>].focus();
```

parent: dummy 1 input gains focus and calls guestChanged function

```
<input name="dummy1" value="" type="readonly" onFocus="javascript: guestChanged(<%=nameCounter%>)" style="width:1px; height:1px; border:0">


   function guestChanged(custPtr) { 
    if (newWindow2 && !newWindow2.closed) {
        newWindow2.close();

        counter = document.star.counter.value*1;
        dummy1 = document.star.dummy1[0].value;     
        errorFlag = false;
            ...etc.
```

As I say, this is working perfectly in IE and until yesterday in Chrome :(
I hope I have explained the circumstances sufficiently well.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Seriously you're using `javascript:` hrefs and you wonder why your code won't work?

Comment: Hi @Lankymart. The javascript works fine to call the child. That's not the problem even though you may not like this method. Can you offer a solution or advice regarding the problem I asked?

Comment: @Lankymart - I have got this working now. will post code just in case someone else runs into similar issue. You were right. Thanks. Because this method has worked for me for years and still does in IE, I was making the whole thing too complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered my own question with a shove in the right direction from @lankymart (thanks)
posted in case of interest to anyone running into same issue

**parent:**

```
<input name="passedGuestId" id="passedGuestId" onFocus="javascript: guestChanged(<%=nameCounter%>)"> 
<input type=button onclick="javascript:openwindow(0)" value="Add Customer"> 

<script language="javascript"> 
function openwindow(ptr) {  
    newWindow2Ref = "www.child.asp";
    window.open(newWindow2Ref,"_blank","height=600,width=600,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no") 
} 
</script>
```

**child:**
in my case, search on form in classic asp then run js, which closes window and returns value

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
   window.opener.document.getElementById('passedGuestId').value="<%=custId%>" 
   window.opener.document.getElementById('passedGuestId').focus();
   window.close() 
// -->
</script>
```

**parent**
on return, input passedGuestId gets focus and calls guestChanged() Js to process the information returned

```
 function guestChanged(custPtr) {
            counter = document.star.counter.value*1;
            dummy1 = document.star.passedGuestId.value;
            errorFlag = false;
etc...
```